# Snake Game Help- not using Pygame(Python)

Tags: python, graphics, cluster-computing, draw

Currently working on designing a snake game using python, with import.draw, without pygame! Most of my game is completed and it is working out very well, except for the fact that any time an arrow is clicked( up,down,left,or right) the length of the snake just becomes bigger, that is not what i want to happen, because the length should only become larger once the snake eats the apple!
This is my code:
    import Draw
    import random

```
Draw.setCanvasSize(600,600)
masterList = [[None for col in range(30)] for row in range(30)]

def startscreen():  #WELCOME SCREEN
#set screen
#(may change to loop later)
Draw.setBackground(Draw.CYAN)
Draw.setColor(Draw.RED)
Draw.filledRect(0,100,600,200)
Draw.setColor(Draw.GREEN)
Draw.filledRect(0,200,600,200)
Draw.setColor(Draw.PINK)
Draw.filledRect(0,200,600,200)
Draw.setColor(Draw.BLUE)
Draw.filledRect(0,300,600,200)
Draw.setColor(Draw.YELLOW)
Draw.filledRect(0,400,600,200)
Draw.setColor(Draw.VIOLET)
Draw.filledRect(0,500,600,200)
Draw.setFontSize(80)
Draw.setFontFamily("Courier")
a = "SNAKE GAME"
Draw.setColor(Draw.BLACK)
Draw.string(a,50,220)
Draw.setFontSize(35)
Draw.string("CLICK ANYWHERE TO CONTINUE",30,330)

def clickAnywhere():
while True:
    if Draw.mousePressed():
        return True

#code for press enter to continue using draw package and keys
def playGame(size):
#choose starting point for apple
appleX = random.randrange(0, 580, 20)
appleY = random.randrange(0, 580, 20)  
positionApple = random.randrange(0, 580, 20) 

masterList[positionApple//20][positionApple//20] = 'a'

# initial position of snake in middle
lengthSnake = 4 # four boxes
positionSnakeX = 300
positionSnakeY = 300
for i in range(15, 19):
    masterList[15][i] = 'x'

drawTheBoard(appleX,appleY, positionSnakeX, positionSnakeY,lengthSnake)

#while positionSnake != 0 and positionSnake != 600:
while True:
    # check if user pressed a key to change snake direction
    if Draw.hasNextKeyTyped():
        newKey = Draw.nextKeyTyped()
        if newKey == "Left":
            positionSnakeX -= 20
            lengthSnake += 1
        elif newKey == "Right":
            positionSnakeX += 20   
            lengthSnake += 1
        elif newKey == "Up":
            positionSnakeY -= 20 
            lengthSnake += 1
        elif newKey == "Down":
            positionSnakeY += 20  
            lengthSnake += 1

        drawTheBoard(appleX,appleY, positionSnakeX, positionSnakeY, 
lengthSnake)


    # if snake hit the apple, then add a box to the snake
    if hitApple(positionSnakeX, positionSnakeY, positionApple, positionApple):
        lengthSnake += 1
        masterList[positionApple/20][positionApple/20] = None
        positionApple = random.randrange(0, 580, 20)
        masterList[positionApple/20][positionApple/20] = 'a'

    #check if snake hit wall using hitWall()
  #      if hitWall(positionSnake, positionSnake):
   #          return False # will this break the while loop 

    # check if snake hit itself

    # otherwise draw the board
    #    drawTheBoard(positionApple, positionSnakeX, positionSnakeY, 
   lengthSnake) # function that clears and resets board after each round
    #def moveSnake(s,dx,dy):
   #head= s[0]
   #news= [[head[0] + dy, head[1]+dx]]+s[0:-1]]
   #return news

 def drawTheBoard(appleX,appleY,snakeX,snakeY,lengthSnake):
#clear Canvas
Draw.clear()
#Draw Snake using for loop to draw the number of rectangles corresponding to
#how many boxes in 2D list it has
Draw.picture("snakeBackground.gif",0,0)
Draw.setColor(Draw.BLACK)
for i in range(lengthSnake):
    Draw.filledRect(snakeX+(20*i), snakeY, 20, 20)
    # change the x, y coordinates based on 2D list

# Draw Apple
Draw.setColor(Draw.RED)
drawApple(appleX, appleY)
if snakeX == appleX and snakeY == appleY:
    drawApple()

    #return true
    #if snake hit wall
    #return False
Draw.show()

 def drawApple(appleX, appleY):
   #appleX = random.randrange(0, 580, 20) 
   #appleY = random.randrange(0, 580, 20) 
   Draw.setColor(Draw.RED)
   Draw.filledOval(appleX, appleY, 20, 20)       

 def hitApple(snakeX, snakeY, appleX, appleY):
if (appleX < snakeX < appleX + 20) or (appleY < snakeY < appleY + 20):
    return True
return False

 #def hitWall(snakeCoords):
#use x, y coordinates to check if snake hit wall, returning True or False
#if snake's x is less than 0 or x is greater than or equal to numCols
#if y is less than 0 or y is greater than or equal to numRows
#return True
# Else, return False
# (0,600) is considered hitting the wall

 def main():
startscreen()
if clickAnywhere():
    Draw.clear()
#clear the screen
snakeSize = 4
#for each of x times
#ans= playGame(size)
#If ans= playGame(size):
#snakeSize += 1
playGame(snakeSize)
```

# Draw.show()
    main()

Answer (score 0):

You execute

```
lengthSnake += 1
```

every time `Draw.hasNextKeyTyped()` is truthy (and the key is "Left"/"Right"/"Up"/"Down").

Answer (score 0):

With this while loop, you are telling the computer each time a key is pressed add one to the length of snake.

```
while True:
    # check if user pressed a key to change snake direction
    if Draw.hasNextKeyTyped():
        newKey = Draw.nextKeyTyped()
        if newKey == "Left":
            positionSnakeX -= 20
            lengthSnake += 1
        elif newKey == "Right":
            positionSnakeX += 20   
            lengthSnake += 1
        elif newKey == "Up":
            positionSnakeY -= 20 
            lengthSnake += 1
        elif newKey == "Down":
            positionSnakeY += 20  
            lengthSnake += 1`enter code here`
```

Remove lengthSnake += 1 from each if block.